# problem executing a bash script with utf8 encoding

Tags: bash, sed, shell-scripting, utf-8

I have a bash script encoded in utf8 .

Within the script i use sed command using `§` as a separator .

Now when i run execute this script `sed` complains about the separator.

If i use normal char  as a separator for ex `@` then everything works.

I have viewed the script in putty[set utf8 in putty] and the character appears fine.

Also Linux default char set from `locale` command shows

```
 LC_CSET=en_US.UTF-8
```

What could have gone wrong?

Earlier i used to have windows-1252 encoding for the shell scripts and this used to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably your version of `sed` does not support multibyte separator characters. If you look at the way `§` is encoded in the two character sets, you'll see the difference:

```
% locale
LANG="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
% printf § > section.utf8
% hexdump -C section.utf8
00000000  c2 a7                                             |..|
00000002
% iconv -f UTF-8 -t WINDOWS-1252 < section.utf8 > section.win1252
% hexdump -C section.win1252
00000000  a7                                                |.|
00000001
```

Various versions of `sed` will give you more or less helpful messages. On my OS X 10.6 system, I get the somewhat cryptic:

```
% sed 's§foo§bar§' 
sed: 1: "s§foo§bar§": RE error: illegal byte sequence
```

The version of `sed` that Ubuntu 10.04 LTS uses is more helpful:

```
% sed 's§foo§bar§'
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: delimiter character is not a single-byte character
```